# JavaFX color as enum

Tags: javafx, enums, colors

I have a `combobox` that's initialized with `public enum nameColor`. I also have a shape that will pull the `Color` from that `combobox`. I can't seem to get my `enum` to represent the `Color` class. When I use `foo.nameColor.BLUE` as an argument for my shape, it doesn't recognize the `value` as a `Color`

```
public static enum nameColor {
    AQUA(Color.AQUA),
    BLACK(Color.BLACK),
    BLUE(Color.BLUE),
    CORAL(Color.CORAL),
    GREEN(Color.GREEN),
    GREY(Color.GREY),
    RED(Color.RED),
    WHITE(Color.WHITE),
    YELLOW(Color.YELLOW);

    private Color nameColor;

    nameColor(Color nameColor){this.nameColor = nameColor;}
    public void setNameColor(Color nameColor){this.nameColor = nameColor;}
    public Color getNameColor(){return nameColor;}
}
```

Comment: You cannot do something like this in java. `Color` is final so you cannot create a subtype and only subtypes would be a type that could also be used in place of a `Color`. Of course you could add a getter to the enum, but youd need to overload any methods taking the `Color` type and you cannot modify classes from the JavaFX API like this without subclassing them...

Comment: You can of course do `myShape.setFill(nameColor.BLUE.getNameColor());`. But none of this really seems to make any sense; you're `enum` doesn't behave like an enum (there's nothing to prevent you doing meaningless things like `nameColor.GREEN.setNameColor(Color.RED)`, for example). Why not simply populate your combo box with the nine `Color` values directly?

Comment: They ```combobox``` would need to appear as ```AQUA```, ```BLUE```, ```GREEN```...etc. I was not sure how to pull the colors to the shape if they are just text values.

Comment: You could probably do something similar to `List of Color Patterns` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF).